# MongoDB in ReplicaSet databases showing different sizes and objects

Tags: replication, mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I have a MongoDB in a ReplicaSet with 3 members, and last week the primary node got corrupted somehow and stopped. I had to resync the data from the other nodes.

It has been a week but I was checking this morning and the databases looks different somehow between the primary (that crashed) and the two secondary that were used for resync the data.

> **PRIMARY (after crash)**

[image]
[image]

> **Secondary**

[image]
[image]

I've seen other questions similar to this one but at the end the databases had the same amount of objects, however, my scenario it isn't the same.

Any idea? Or does it look ok?

Comment: I would say that it's OK.. After successful initial sync, everything transferred, even `objects` count is little bit different.

Comment: @JJussi is there a way to verify that files match? Or execute something at the secondaries to sync in Size and Objects?

Comment: You can check that both have the same count of documents with itcount() (count() gives result from meta data, itcount() counts every document). Reason, why size and objects are different is compression and fact that initial sync copies only what is needed, so all deleted or updated objects (original parts) are not copied.

Answer (score 3):

The **`rsync`** process will also apply a `de-fragmentation` for the MongoDB data files on the crashed primary replica. That's why you see the data file reduced in size on the primary after crashed.

This effect is the same if you run the [compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#dbcmd.compact) command on your secondary to reclaim the fragmented storage caused by data CRUD operations over time.